# Network jitter using wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, ping, wifi-configuration, jitter

I have a weird issue with my home network but it only happens a few random days. The issue is that I get a lot of jitter suddenly without any explanation.

Setup:

- 1 router serving a 5 GHz network on channel 64 (call this "Network/router A")
- 1 router serving a 5 GHz network on channel 104 (call this "Network/router B")
- Router B is connected to router A
- Router A is the main one, fiber connected

Network B is a more powerful router that covers the entire home. All my devices connect there.
Network A is only used by one computer, my tower. (not feasible to get it wired).

My networks' channels were manually set and you can see they're the only network in that channel.

All my devices connected via wifi to **either network** suffer from jitter when the problem occurs (which can be once a week or something).

I've tested my raspberry pi which is wired to the router and it **doesn't suffer form the same jitter.**

**The question is**, what is causing this random jitter that happens maybe once a week while using wifi???

EDIT
by jitter I mean my ping is steady (decent average) but the deviation is very high. Pinging my Router A using wifi I get 1-3ms but every few seconds it rises to 100-200ms

Neighbor networks:
[image: netspot]

[image: pingplotter]

[image: android device pinging]

Comment: I think it is important to define “jitter” and how you are measuring it? Are you referring to high and inconsistent ping times as jitter? It is not. What problem are you specifically experiencing? Are you actually measuring your WiFi network only? Or are you measuring your internet connection as well? Simple scheduled events could cause inconsistent ping times on your network by simply transferring large amounts of data. Windows updates, file downloads and uploads. Etc.

Comment: @andrepcg I wish you would not post such LARGE pictures in here like this, it would be much easier for lesser kbps wifi modems to download in our browsers. Appleoddity, Very Good Comment.

Comment: @Appleoddity by jitter I mean my ping is steady (decent average) but the deviation is very high. Pinging my Router A using wifi I get 1-3ms but every few seconds it rises to 100-200ms

Comment: I thought it could be my network (or a device inside) causing this issue, but I tried a public wifi nearby and the issue is still present no matter the device that connects. I even tried disconnecting all devices from my network and connecting one by one and the issue is still there as well

Comment: If the issue persists throughout multiple networks with the same device it's likely that the device is at fault. It might be doing some sort of "housekeeping", getting updates or similar.